# VBA PasteSpecial sometimes pasting data from other(not given one ) cell

Tags: excel, vba

Here I am unable to find what is the mistake in my code ,can any one find that

my aim is to copy data from one sheet to other sheet -for destination sheet I have given cell reference to paste data from that cell

exact scenario is updating LOV sheet with report output sheet

my problem : sometimes data is pasting from other cells like E10,A15,F7 instead of A2 or B2

```
 Dim oFSO As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFile As Object

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\LOV_" & nw)
Dim k As Long
k = 1
For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    k = k + 1
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(oFile)
    Dim LastRow As Long
    With wb.Sheets(1)
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row '  Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    wb.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Copy
    cel = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("controls").Cells(k, "H").Value & "2"
    Debug.Print cel
    Sheet5.Range(cel).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
 ' Sheet5.Range(Sheet2.Range(k, "H").Value & "2").Font.colourIndex = 1
 'Sheet5.Range(cel).Font.ColorIndex = vbGreen

Application.CutCopyMode = False

      wb.Close False
Next
```

in the above code **cel** is column name --in which column I want to paste --to make dynamic I have kept column data in another sheet

Comment: This isn't going to be reproducible. What does `Debug.Print cel` return in the Immediate Window?

Comment: A2 ,B2  two only it showing but pasting in other cell   ,in first iteration it have copy from A2,next from B2

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is here.

Comment: thanks for your response ,here my problem is with step in  paste cell is showing exactly (A2 ,B2) but pasting in other references

Comment: As mentioned by BigBen. With `cel = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("controls").Cells(k, "H").Value & "2"` you are using value in kth row and column H + 2 as target address for pasting. It will keep changing with k. You can debug the code running it using F8 key. ad when check value of cel with each iteration.

Comment: okay thank you naresh ,After changing paste method it's working but I think there is no difference--           wb.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Copy Destination:=Sheet5.Range(cel)

Comment: In my post code I have commented two lines when I uncomment that I am getting runtime error -METHOD RANGE OF OBJECT _WORKSHEET FAILED      Sheet5.Range(Sheet2.Range(k, "H").Value & "2").Font.colourIndex = 1   why that error is coming